# How to trigger the modal of datetime-local input type on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Case: User clicks on a button and triggers only the modal of datetime-local. The input itself would be hidden.

Unlike with the input type file, click function does not seem to work.

Comment: `[input]type = file` can be simulated with a click because it is a button. `[input]type = datetime-local` will do nothing when clicked because it is not a button. If you want to have something like that, I suggest the jQuery date picker because that can be visibly controlled.

Answer (score 2):

You can hide most of the input contents and keep and stylize the calendar using css pseudo-classes for shadow dom. The calendar could be used as a button

```
::-webkit-datetime-edit {
    display: none;
}

::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
```